# Selenium Java - How to modify the MIME type of an excel file before uploading it to the server?

Tags: java, excel, selenium, apache-poi, mime-types

I'm trying to upload an excel file using Selenium's sendKeys() method after writing on it using POI.
Once the file is uploaded, the server rejects it as its MIME type is "application/zip" and it's set to accept "application/vnd.ms-excel" only.

Is there a way to modify the file's MIME type before uploading it?

Using Firefox and Chrome result in the same behavior:

Firefox Setup: Selenium 3.4.0, geckodriver 0.16.1 x64, Firefox 53.0 x64.

Chrome Setup: Selenium 3.4.0, chromedriver x64, Chrome 57.0 x64.

I'm also running Java 1.8.0_121 on a Windows 10 machine.

Thanks.

Edit: When the same file is saved normally (using MS-Excel) and uploaded, the server accepts it (the mime type is received as "application/vnd.ms-excel" on the server side).

Comment: could you post the code on how you do the upload?

Comment: browseButton.sendKeys(filePath);

uploadButton.click();

where browseButton and uploadButton are WebElements in the page object.